# Insert data into temporary table from dynamic query table output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have the below dynamic query run in SQL Server, connecting to an OLAP server using a linked server, which returns a table as a result.

```
SET @nSQL = EXECUTE ('SELECT non empty {
[Coded Season].[Coded Season].[Coded Season] *
[Season].[Season].[Season] *
[Product].[Subclass].[Subclass] *
[Product].[Subclass Id].[Subclass Id]
} ON ROWS,{
[Measures].[Pl No of Range Opts]
} ON COLUMNS
FROM RP_C0') AT AS_T_RP_5900_Admin
```

I am executing it in SQL Server like this:

```
exec sp_executesql @nSQL;
```

It returns a table of values. Now I want to insert the data into a temporary table. I have tried the below code, but its not working.

```
INSERT INTO ##Subclass_Season_AS 
exec sp_executesql @nSQL;
```

Also tried,

```
set @strNewQuery ='SELECT '+@nSQL+' INTO ##temptablename '
exec @strNewQuery
```

Could you please help on this? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Could you show the `##Subclass_Season_AS`  table definition?

Comment: Hi, This is the table defintion.CREATE TABLE ##Subclass_Season_AS
 ([Coded Season] VARCHAR(10),
 [Subclass Id] VARCHAR(40),
 [Season] VARCHAR(40),
 [Pl No of Range Opts] INT). Incorrect syntax is the error I am getting.

Comment: Instead using `AT AS_T_RP_5900_Admin` could add the linked server name in front of each table name?

Comment: *"its not working*" >> This is not enough of a problem description. Describe please (in your question) what you mean by that. Does your statement result in a compiler error, a run-time error, incorrect results...? Also, please add a tag to your question for the specific SQL Server version(s) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to put the INTO statement in your dynamic query.

```
SET @nSQL = EXECUTE ('SELECT non empty {
[Coded Season].[Coded Season].[Coded Season] *
[Season].[Season].[Season] *
[Product].[Subclass].[Subclass] *
[Product].[Subclass Id].[Subclass Id]
} ON ROWS,{
[Measures].[Pl No of Range Opts]
} ON COLUMNS
INTO ##temptablename
FROM RP_C0') AT AS_T_RP_5900_Admin
```